# How to add tags to a resource from the Azure portal?

Tags: azure, tags

I am trying to follow the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-using-tags) to add tags to one of my virtual machines deployed on Microsoft Azure. However, when I go to "Tags" in the menu, all I get is the following sceen with no option to add tags:

[image: Adding tags to Azure]

The logged in user is an admin user. What am I missing?

[image: Admin user]

Comment: Could you see `tags` on your VM interface?

Answer (score 1):

The permission you are looking for is called `"Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/write"` if I'm not mistaken
You can create a custom role to assign that or use one of the built-in roles, like contributor.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-custom-roles#actions

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-built-in-roles#role-permissions

Comment: But the logged in user is an admin, why do I need to assign special permissions to add tags?

Comment: i don't believe in miracles, user you are using to access the portal is clearly lacking permissions. try clearing cookies\cache, try incognito mode, try another browser, another PC (if you are sure you are using admin user)

Comment: Nope, no luck still.

Answer (score 0):

Hi by the looks of your screenshot you have opted to be able to see both Classic and ARM VMs.  I can't see from the shot which type you are working on, but you can't add tags to classic VMs - is this a Classic VM?

This is detailed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-using-tags

Ian

Comment: I am not trying to apply tags, I am trying to create one- so that should be independent of where I will apply those. The screenshot attached is when I am trying to create a tag.

Comment: Hi Jobin I think I see the problem.  I don't believe you can create a tag outside of a resource.  For example you can apply tags to a VM or a Resource Group, you can then click on that tag and see any other resource with that same tag.  The view you are using (Tags) lists the tags aassocaited with resources and lets you navigate them.  You can use ARM policies to define required tags and values.